# Polymer Custom Element Shadow DOM issues

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, shadow-dom

I am attempting to use the Polymer shadow DOM " $ " object.

```
document.querySelector("recent-activity-section").$
```

This code should return an object that looks like this:

```
Object {recent-activity-section: section#recent-activity-section, recent-activity-div: div#recent-activity-div, list: core-list#list}
```

In fact, using the Chrome Dev Tools console, it does.

However, inside of the "created" function in the javascript file that goes along with my custom element, I get the following:

```
undefined
```

Perhaps I'm using something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `created` method, which is one of the first ones triggered in the element's lifecycle, you would probably have more luck using **`domReady`**, which is, according to [Polymer official docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods):

> Called when the element’s initial set of children are guaranteed to exist. This is an appropriate time to poke at the element’s parent or light DOM children.